# nuget command is not reconized in jenkins pipeline

Tags: .net, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm using jenkins installed in my windows laptop and trying to perform the continious integration of an ASP.Net project.

I installed nuget.exe. when I try to make a stage which inclure a nuget command that doesn't work for me.

```
stage ('Restore Packages'){
        bat '"C:\\tools\\nuget.exe" restore Solution.sln'

 }

'"C:\\tools\\nuget.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program, or a batch file
```

So can any one helps me?

Comment: can you try to add `steps` in your stage and add `bat` with every operation?

Comment: bat already exist

Comment: and when i add steps he told me that no such DSL method

Comment: Did you override the installation of .NET Core? The path `C:\Program Files\dotnet.exe` is not where the `dotnet` executable lives by default.

Comment: No, and I editet the question because nuget restore should be runned and not dotnet restore.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this command:

```
bat label: '', script: 'C:\\tools\\nuget.exe restore Solution.sln'
```

In case you happen to have space somewhere in the directory path (for example, `C:\Program Files`), you can use the following pattern:

```
bat label: '', script: '"C:\\Program Files (x86)"\\tools\\nuget.exe restore Solution.sln'
```

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes not required!
Use this code:

**stage('Restore packages'){**

**bat 'C:\tools\nuget.exe restore Solution.sln'**

**}**